# Why do some APPs see atached USB drives biut others do not?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a laptop that I have been Ububtu on for a few years now. I currently running 22.04 with all of the current up dates and no beta software. I have, addition to the 500G internal HDD, three USB connected drives. One (1) 1 TB, (1) 4TB drive formatted as (2) 1 TB drives, and a third 16 TB    The issue I am having is that, while I can see and access all files on all of the drives listed above. Some APPs can not. Again I want to be clear. I CAN see the all of the drives. I can open Firefox and save a file or photo to any directory, anywhere on the system, as well as pull any file to upload to the web. Like wise, I can open Rhytm Box and add music to the APP from any where and play the music from that location.

The issue I am having is that some APPs do NOT see these connected UBS drives. Two examples are MUSIC app. It ony see the songs on the local drive. As well as SCREEN SAVER. It will only see photos on the local drives.

SO what is the issue?

Comment: The apps that do not see the drives are probably [SNAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software)) apps since they are sandboxed.

Comment: What is "MUSIC app?" There is no such application by that name on a stock install of Ubuntu, so it's unclear which application you are referring to. Help us to help you.

Comment: It's not. It's an add on APP that you gett from the "Ubuntu Software" store(?). You are correct that it not part of the default install.. Looks likes the pesron who also answered has the answer I needed. But thank for trying to help,